# Laravel Ajax cannot update database when click on a link

Tags: ajax, database, laravel

I have an audio file on public folder like this-

```
@foreach ($songs as $song)
     <a href="{{asset('/audio/' . $song->song)}}" download="" >
        <button type="button" class="download" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download">Download</i>
        </button>
     </a>
 @endforeach
```

So, when i click that button it downloads the song. In my database, in "song" table there is column for song and another one for download_count which is set to default(0). I try to update download_count when i click on the link by ajax. My ajax:

```
$(function() {
  $('.download').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: "/update_download_count",
   type:"POST",
   data: {
     song_id:$(this).attr('data-id')
   }
  });
});
    });
```

My Route:

```
Route::post('/update_download_count', 'PagesController@updateDownloadCount');
```

Controller:

```
public function updateDownloadCount(){
         $song_id = $_POST['song_id'];
         $song->download += 1;
         $song->save();
}
```

But, i cannot update my database however i click on the link. it still set to 0 in download_count column. Plz help, what's the wrong?

Comment: first step is to not use $_POST[] in laravel, inject your Request and read the data out of your request variable. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

Comment: you have not declared modal for $song. Please use below $song = Song::findOrFail($id);

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually select the song.

```
public function updateDownloadCount(Request $request) {
    $song = Song::find($request->input("song_id"));
    $song->download += 1;
    $song->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please declare object for your song modal.

```
public function updateDownloadCount() {
     $song = Song::findOrFail($_POST['song_id']);
     $song->download += 1;
     $song->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateDownloadCount(Request $request){
     \DB::table('songs')->where('songs_id', $request->input("song_id"))->increment('download');
}
```

Comment: not working bro. I think there is something wrong with my ajax call. cant figure out

Comment: dd($request->input("song_id"));  check value exist or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$song->download += 1;
```

Try:

```
Song::find($request->input("song_id"))->increment('download');
```

I think that should work